# file.delete(); nothing happening

Tags: java, file-io

I've had this before and I can't for the life of me remember what the issue was...

I was trying to use `file.delete();` but the file wasn't being deleted, no errors or anything, so tried this:

```
public void removeFile(File file){
     file.delete();
     System.out.println(file.canRead());
     System.out.println(file.canWrite());
     System.out.println(file);
     System.out.println(file.delete());
 }
```

it returns:

```
C:\contest\dpd\
true
true
C:\contest\dpd\out\408.OUT
false
```

Note: Running on Windows 7. The file in question is not open by any other program, it doesn't have read-only set.

Comment: Are you running the application as an admin?

Comment: Is this file created by the current application?

Comment: Is the file currently open by *this* application?

Comment: @KevinBowersox  If there was an exception, the line outputting to the console wouldn't execute ;)

Comment: @GETah , as I said in my post, no it is not read only.

Comment: @KevinBowersox It does indeed say that, and SecurityException extends RuntimeException, so you don't need to catch it, and the evidence of the output supplied shows that no exception is being thrown. So he doesn't need to put this method into a try catch block.

Comment: @Reimeus, I'm running this from eclipse, the file was created earlier from eclipse, since then I've re-run it.

Comment: Try `System.out.println(file.exists());`.

Comment: `System.out.println(file.delete())` is expected to display `false` as it is the second time you are calling `file.delete()`

Comment: @GETah, even after commenting out the first delete it still returns false

Comment: @Eng.Fouad  System.out.println(file.exists());   returns true

Comment: @Mark does the file still exist after the first delete()? After the second? As observed externally, not via this code.

Comment: @Mark Ok try the new [`Files.delete()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#delete(java.nio.file.Path)), it would throw exception with a message explaining the issue if exists.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad, apologies for not explaining first, this is using Java 6

Comment: @Eng.Fouad I used the Files.delete() and temporarily changed runtime to Java7.  Says file is in use by another process... However I can't see why/how.  I can delete the file from cmd.exe and from windows explorer ...

Comment: @Mark Please also clarify whether the first delete() returns true or false.

Comment: @EJP the first delete returns false

Comment: You can delete the file from cmd.exe/explorer at the same moment this method runs? I'm starting to suspect you still have the file open yourself.

Comment: Ah ok, well not solved it but narrowed it down.  @EJP looks like you're probably right... File is deleted if I use file.deleteOnExit();
Suggesting somewhere along the line the file is open and not closed.

Comment: feel a little stupid:
The file is being used by a reader that wasn't closed until after the delete was called (reader.close())
Cheers for the help all ^

Comment: @Mark I would encourage you, then, to answer and accept your own question. This can help future users with the same problem.

Comment: @Jeff ok, have added a summary of my stupidity, cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok as per my comments, the answer was me being foolish.

The file is used:

```
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
```

The reader wasn't closed

> reader.close();

Perhaps if somebody gets this sort of problem and come across this question, trace the use of file back, checking where it's being accessed, checking anything that is using it, releases it before the delete function is callled.

Comment: Will do, have to wait 48 hours to accept an answer for a question you ask yourself apparently :)